# How do I enforce a certain type of Service is only used by a certain type of Entity

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, interface

I am trying to design an application, where in I am stuck at a simple problem.
we have two types of Users `IUser` and `IAdministrator` and then we have two service classes called `IUserOperationsService` and `IAdministratorOperationsService`. Based on what type of user is logged on we want to decide what operations are available. but my question is how do I enforce that Administrative operations are only available to `IAdministrator` and not `IUser`

IUser -

```
public interface IUser
{
    string UserName { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

IAdministrator-

```
public interface IAdministrator : IUser
{
}
```

IUserOperationsService-

```
public interface IUserOperationsService
{
    IUser GetUserByUserId(short userId);
}
```

IAdministratorOperationsService-

```
public interface IAdministratorOperationsService
{
    short AddUser(IUser user);
    bool DeleteUser(IUser user);
    bool EditUser(IUser user);
}
```

Comment: How is IUser/IAdministrator instantiated while logging on?

Comment: database has an isAdmin check, when user logs in, we will check what type of user is requesting

Comment: You can make `AddUser` etc. require `IAdministrator` instance as an argument. But you still need to check whether given object is not null so you may as well check for `isAdmin` field during runtime. I am not sure what you want to achieve. Are you trying to enforce security this way or just want to make programmer errors less probable?

Comment: trying to implement security..

Comment: Then how do you make sure your program instantiate `IUser` and not `IAdministrator` when `isAdmin` is false? There is a level *somewhere* where program is omnipotent.

Comment: You could try sticking to single `IUser` interface with `IsAdmin` property and use aspect oriented programming to annotate methods that require `IUser` to return true on this field.

Comment: hmm, you mean everytime I call a method I make a check if user isAdmin or not ?

Comment: You have to check it *somewhere* anyway. I believe you are trying to use *compile* time tools to enforce *runtime* security checks. Unless I am missing something - the best you can do is help yourself make safer code (by avoiding errors and oversights).

Comment: I would have preferred to have a design wherein only IAdmin could call IadministratorService, but cant find a way